# Allow only 3 numbers

Tags: javascript

I want to make a javascript (or jquery) function that works onChange and allow only to write 3 numbers : 5, 15 or 25

If the user write an other value (example 3 or 4...), the input have to be reset to 0

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help, if you are using jQuery:

```
$('.myField').change(function() {
  var field = $(this);
  var values = new Array("5", "15", "25");

  $.inArray(field.val(), values) >= 0 ? /* Everything is ok */ : field.val("0");
});
```

I'm not sure if `change()` will give you strange performance issues. It if does, try `blur()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. As you can tell, I didn't test it. :) I get the val() assignment mixed up sometimes, too.

Comment: @Matt: `in` won't work like that. The only numbers that will return true will be `0,1,2` since `in` is looking for properties, not values.

Comment: @patrick d'ahhh you're right. I tested it in the console and everything. `</duncecap>`

Comment: Ok, then, I just made a change which I knew would work. Thanks for the pointers, guys.

Comment: @spryno724: An alternative would be `field.val() in {5:1,15:1,25:1}`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm thinking the way I have it above will be a bit easier to add/drop values in the future.

Comment: @spryno724: I'd agree with that.

Comment: @spryno724 : the code have not worked ; 
I have used like this : 
$('.qty').change(function(e) {
    if(this.value != '5' && this.value != '15' && this.value != '25') {
        this.value = '0';   
    }
});

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to limit the possible values that strictly, a `<select>` is **by far** the best way to do this.

```
<select>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>15</option>
    <option>25</option>
</select>
```

Works with JavaScript disabled. Completely browser compatible. Screen-reader friendly.

Comment: I have to use an input text field !

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish that elegantly using the jQuery Validation plugin

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

It has many features for automatic form validation.

Comment: @patrick: OP said jQuery is ok. I'd suggest that it's bleedin' heavy for this tiny use case, though.